# Add TU-Berlin MS Exchange Account: Failed to find ASUrl and OABUrl in autodiscover response

Tags: 18.04, online-accounts, ms-exchange

I try to add my university exchange account to Ubuntu 18.04 using *Settings* > *Online Accounts* > *Microsoft Exchange* with the following settings:

Email: username@tu-berlin.de
Passwort: *****
Username: username
Server: exchange.tu-berlin.de

After clicking *Connect* the following error message appears:
`Error connecting to Microsoft Exchange Server: Failed to find ASUrl and OABUrl in autodiscover response`

Somethere on our TU pages is written to use *win* for outgoing post. So I try this setting too:

Email: username@win.tu-berlin.de
Passwort: *****
Username: username
Server: win.tu-berlin.de

After clicking *Connect* the following error message appears:
`Error connecting to Microsoft Exchange Server: Cannot find WebDAV endpoint`

What is the Problem here? Is there a way to setup the account on a manual way (which and how)?

I do not intend to use Evolution or Thunderbird. I'm only interested in getting the calendar synchronised.

Comment: WebDAV may not be enabled for Exchange in this case, or at least not WebDAV *directly*.  But that is an Exchange Server setting, not an Ubuntu one.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your alex@example.com is a [Microsoft Outlook for business](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/outlook/outlook-for-business), set your email and password as usual. At the custom fields:

- **Username:** alex@example.com
- **Server:** [outlook.office365.com](https://outlook.office365.com)

[image: ubuntu-accounts]

Answer (score 4):

Despite your question being a litte dated, I would like to refer to the following [bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-online-accounts/-/issues/68).

According to this report, "Gnome Online Accounts" behaves differently than "evolution-ews" - the former still requires the "OABUrl" in the Exchange answer. However, newer Exchange servers by default send autodiscovery messages that no longer contain it.

So if this error occurs, the only solution is to connect the account directly in Evolution (and not use GOA here).
(Unless the IT administrator can be persuaded to change the server configuration so that the URL is included in the response again.)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to configure my company Cloud Exchange Account (Office.com) with Gnome Online Accounts, but I could not find the proper way to do it, so, I did it in Evolution, which works pretty well for now. 
You need to check the right configuration first, which should be something similar to what I did:
Usually in https://outlook.office.com/owa/ you can access them from the top-right side of the sreen (from your point of view):

`Settings-icon (screw) → 'Your app settings' → Mail → [left side menu] Options → Mail → Accounts → 'Pop and IMAP'`.

And there you can get the information related to server address, port and encryption type.
You can manually add these parameters, taking into account that probably you will have to configure, in the Evolution's `Account Editor → Sending Email → Authentication` the type as Login, as well as the right encryption method, in my case, `"STARTTLS after connecting"`.

I hope this helps you